# Equation referencing

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, lyx, tags

LyX correctly infers the equation number from the compiled document and displays its correct equation number.
The LxY:Cross-reference dialog, however, only shows the label, but not the equation number. In the screenshot below, `eq:VolInt` (instead of `5,eq:VolInt`).

Can this dialog be changed to include the equation number, as it appears in the document? In the depicted example, the dialog should offer `5,eq:VolInt` (instead of `eq:VolInt`).

With that, cross-referencing in documents would be much more comfortable.

[image: Can LyX offer (5,eq:VolInt) instead of eq:VolInt?]

Comment: I fear this is off-topic here. This is a question for the LyX team.

Comment: Questions about LyX are [on topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Indeed this question is not about the LaTeX language directly. But there many questions here that are not directly about the LaTeX language and are considered on-topic. Some are about LaTeX editors, some are about LaTeX development, some are about CTAN practices, some are about installing packages, etc. The important thing is to make sure questions are tagged correctly, so that they can be ignored by those that choose.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned from the LyX team now that the desired feature will be available as of 2.4.